# What is the difference between a welcome page and a home page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing, ootb, default

I am working in SharePoint 2016, but I think the question would apply to 2010 or 2013 as well. Let me summarize what I do know, to make my question clear.

- The default page is what a browser loads when I type in just the name of my site, and not an specific page.
- For example, if my SharePoint site is *[www.awesome.com](http://www.awesome.com)*, and I type *[www.awesome.com](http://www.awesome.com)* in my browser, it  would resolve to *[www.awesome.com/default.aspx](http://www.awesome.com/default.aspx)* by default.
- If I have Site Pages enabled, I can set any Site Page as the Home Page from the Ribbon. Thus, if I set Home.aspx as my Home Page, and I type *[www.awesome.com](http://www.awesome.com)* in my browser, it would now resolve to *[www.awesome.com/SitePages/Home.aspx](http://www.awesome.com/SitePages/Home.aspx)*.
- If I have Publishing enabled, I have a Publishing Pages library, Pages, available as well. I also  have a Welcome Page setting listed in Site Settings. I can choose any page from the Pages library, for example, *[www.awesome.com/Pages/Home.aspx](http://www.awesome.com/Pages/Home.aspx)*.

So my question is, what is the difference between the Welcome Page and the Home Page? They both seem to serve the same purpose, to redirect browsers to a specific page by default. But which one overrides the other? If I have Home Page already set, do I need to set a Welcome Page?

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT: What purpose does the sharepoint-server tag serve? To distinguish from SharePoint Online, or what?

Comment: Yes, and to classify the post, so that this post would be exposed to more community users and those who are searching under this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could set a site homepage which is stored in the Pages (or Site Pages) library of your site.

There is only one site homepage in a site, the homepage set later overwrites the homepage set before.

You could make the site home page via Page ribbon> make home page or Welcome page settings, it's the same thing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, you are saying setting the Home Page from the Ribbon or the Welcome Page from Site Settings is the same function? I wish they used the same term then. The difference is that from the Welcome Page, you MUST choose a Publishing Page if you have Managed Navigation turned on.